# An up-to-date SQLite ODBC driver

Tags: sqlite, odbc

Since one of my SQLite db file has been managed by the latest SQLite version (3.39.2), I am no longer able to access the tables through the [ODBC driver](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/). There is no error when connecting to the database, but the list of tables remains empty.

I have a suspicion that this is because it is seriously behind, since it's built on version 3.32.3.

Is there any other more recent ODBC driver for SQLite available out there?

Comment: Which os? There is also a commercial one

Comment: What do you mean the list of tables?

Comment: On Windows. I'm looking for a freeware driver. In Access, Excel, etc., when you connect to an SQLite db with the ODBC driver, you're presented with a list of tables and views. That window remains empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have played with the SQLiteODBC driver last year (I used it with Excel 2002 and 2016) and patched the official scripts to enable builds that include current SQLite release. The details are [here](https://pchemguy.github.io/SQLite-ICU-MinGW/).

I have just recompiled both x32 and x64 SQLiteODBC installers for Windows and uploaded them to my [repo](https://github.com/pchemguy/SQLite-ICU-MinGW/tree/master/bin-SQLiteODBC-Win-x32x64). You can install those or, if you wish, follow my docs and build the driver yourself (you would still need to use several patched scripts included in my repo).

Besides including the current SQLite release, I also enabled most of the extra extensions, which are not included in the official ODBC builds.